# What does "bang two fishes above their head" mean?

Tags: idioms, slang

The context is "Then there are those people who come to it who have had enough of the trauma of abuse, who have tried ‘everything’ to heal but to no avail– and who would be willing to bang two fishes above their head if they thought it might help!"

What does "bang two fishes above their head" mean? Is it an Australian slang? Because the author is Australian. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It means they’re willing try try anything to be healthy again - even something absurd. It literally means banging two fishes above their heads.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I was wondering if it was a special idiom or slang.

Comment: It's not clear whose head is meant. After all ,the plural is sometimes omitted for attributed nouns. 

*above* can mean *on, over*. Anglers finish the catch by knocking a fish over the head. That's my first allusion to the quote.

I did not find evidence of the phrase constituting an idiom, but I did not look very far.